# strings.xml: Error: Found item String/button more than one time

Tags: android

`strings.xml: Error: Found item String/button more than one time`

how to rid off this problem??help

[image]

Comment: Give a different name to each string resource. You have 3 strings with the same name: button

Comment: Google always breaks things. Older versions of Android Studio would not let you define duplicate strings like current versions are doing right now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot have multiple strings with same name ("button") in your case. Give unique name to each of them as follows

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">CourtCounter</string>
    <string name="button1">Button1</string>
    <string name="button2">Button2</string>
    <string name="button3">Button3</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:-

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">CourtCounter</string>
    <string name="button1">Button1</string>
    <string name="button2">Button2</string>
    <string name="button3">Button3</string>
</resources>
```