# Building snapdragon camera application with android studio

Tags: android, android-resources

I am building snapdragon application with Android Studio. I am facing same string more than one time issue.

1) Import project (Gradle, Eclipse....)
2) Add maven and google dependencies
3) Android gradle plugin version = 3.4.0, gradle version = 5.4 
4) Build Project

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy2wZ.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strings.xml: Error: Found item String/button more than one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51184284/strings-xml-error-found-item-string-button-more-than-one-time)

Answer (score 0):

The string "no_storage" is writed in the strings.xml file multiple times. See your strings.xml and check if you've writed "no_storage" multiple times.

Also you can see this thread: [strings.xml: Error: Found item String/button more than one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51184284/strings-xml-error-found-item-string-button-more-than-one-time)